# Is my attached DependencyProperty leaking when subscribing to a long-lived object event?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, dependency-properties, windows-phone

I've been writing a little Silverlight helper class to implement an attached property that can be bound to an `ICollection` / `INotifyCollectionChanged` and toggles the visibility of the target object when the bound collection is empty.

I don't have the full grasp of the `DependencyProperty` behavior regarding memory management and object lifecycle.

Here's the source :

```
public class DisplayOnCollectionEmpty : DependencyObject
{
    #region Constructor and Static Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// This is not a constructable class, but it cannot be static because 
    /// it derives from DependencyObject.
    /// </summary>
    private DisplayOnCollectionEmpty()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    public static object GetCollection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(CollectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCollection(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CollectionProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Collection.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Collection", typeof(object), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(OnCollectionPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnCollectionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = d as FrameworkElement;

        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler onCollectionChanged = (sender, collectionChangedEventArgs) =>
        {
            fe.Visibility = GetVisibility(e.NewValue as ICollection);
        };

        if (e.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue).CollectionChanged -= onCollectionChanged;
        }
        if (e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.NewValue).CollectionChanged += onCollectionChanged;
        }

        fe.Visibility = GetVisibility(e.NewValue as ICollection);
    }

    private static Visibility GetVisibility(ICollection collection)
    {
        if (collection == null) return Visibility.Visible;
        return collection.Count < 1 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: A few notes: 1. A class that declares an attached property does not need to derive from DependencyObject. Hence no need for the private constructor. 2. The ownerType (3rd) parameter in RegisterAttached must be the declaring class, DisplayOnCollectionEmpty here, not FrameworkElement.

Comment: And why don't you directly bind a FrameworkElement's Visibility to a Collection and use an appropriate [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Clemens : I don't use IValueConverter because I also want to change the value when the Collection is updated, AFAIK I can't do that with IValueConverter because it does not expose the target DependencyObject or DependencyProperty.

Thanks for the help in the first post. So there is no way to specify that I want my attachedproperty to be available only on specific types (here FrameworkElement) ?

Comment: Ah, i should have seen that. You can specify that the property can only be applied to FrameworkElement by using FrameworkElement as parameter type in GetCollection and SetCollection, instead of DependencyObject.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are subscribing to the INotifyCollectionChanged's CollectionChanged when the collection is set and only unscribe from it when it's changed.

I would also handle the Unloaded event for the FrameworkElement by unscribing from the CollectionChanged event.

I see you do not check about e.OldValue or e.NewValue being null.

Instead of a dependency property, for the same purpose you could use a Behavior. It's mainly the same thing I think. I haven't thought yet of the pros or cons.
Here are few interesting links talking about behavior vs dependency properties:
[Interactivity.Behavior<T> vs attached properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327554/wpf-interactivity-behaviort-vs-attached-properties)

https://web.archive.org/web/20130622113553/http://briannoyes.net/2012/12/20/AttachedBehaviorsVsAttachedPropertiesVsBlendBehaviors.aspx

Comment: Cleanup on Unloaded can sometimes be unreliable in the sense that controls can be Unloaded and then Loaded again depending on various factors, such as how their parent control behaves when its visibility is changed, etc.  This can leave the bound attached property intact but because the event handler has been disconnected the attached property no longer has any effect.